# How do i reduce padding on codename one charts

Tags: codenameone

How do i close the padding between chart title and the chart. See image attached 
[image: Gap Between Chart title and the chart is to large.]

Comment: We need to see some code to try to figure out what is going on (please) :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest placing the chart into a `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` instead of what I assume is the center of a `BorderLayout`. The center of the `BorderLayout` stretches to take up available space and the chart aligns to the center. The box layout will give the chart the full width and its preferred height.